# Open Windows Camera from Python application

Tags: python, windows

I need to open the Windows 10 camera app and possibly close it after a few seconds so that my camera will work the proper way. I've read in realted questions that I'm supposed to use `os.subprocess.run()` but I'm not sure what should go in there. I've seen posts about opening the Camera from the command line by doing `start microsoft.windows.camera` in the command line but it's not working. Any idea?

Comment: Open the appmanually and check the Task Manager what is executed. - Go to Details in Task Manager, show column with cmd - forgot its name in English, but it's basically the command that should give the same result.

Comment: The appl is placed in C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsCamera_xxx but if I try to open the exe I'm told that I don't have the permission

Comment: I've run it with `start shell:appsfolder\Microsoft.WindowsCamera_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App` but don't know where to take '_8wekyb3d8bbwe'-part

Comment: *"open the Windows 10 camera app and possibly close it after a few seconds so that my camera will work the proper way"* - What *problem* are you really trying to solve? This reads like an [XY Problem](http://xypriblem.info).

Comment: @IInspectable the problem is related to openCV and a logitech Webcam, but it's not important for the question

Answer (score 3):

To open camera:

```
import subprocess,os
subprocess.run('start microsoft.windows.camera:', shell=True)
```

To close camera:

```
subprocess.run('Taskkill /IM WindowsCamera.exe /F', shell=True)
```

If it says it doesn't recognise- WindowsCamera.exe    Type `Tasklist` into your computers command prompt and look for what your camera is called before .exe then adapt the above code to your camera name.

code all together, to check if works:

```
import subprocess,time,os
subprocess.run('start microsoft.windows.camera:', shell=True)
time.sleep(10)
subprocess.run('Taskkill /IM WindowsCamera.exe /F', shell=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

So, with comments

```
import subprocess

subprocess.run('start microsoft.windows.camera:', shell=True)

#camera = subprocess.Popen('start microsoft.windows.camera:', shell=True)
#camera.terminate()  # don't work, access denied :(
```

works, but I can't close camera from script

Comment: CMD always falls back on `ShellExecuteEx` if a file isn't a PE executable, but it only runs files found on disk, unless we use its internal `start` command. "microsoft.windows.camera:" is a registered command, so we need `start`, e.g. `subprocess.call('start microsoft.windows.camera:', shell=True)`.

Comment: Since this command requires no parameters,  we should also be able to use `os.startfile('microsoft.windows.camera:')`, which avoids creating an intermediary cmd.exe process. However, if we need to wait on or terminate the process, if that's even possible for the given command, we need to call `ShellExecuteEx` directly via PyWin32 or ctypes.

Comment: I'm fine closing it manually for the moment but this seems overly complicated

Comment: @AlessandroGaballo, do you mean that having to close it manually is overly complicated, or that running `os.startfile('microsoft.windows.camera:')` is overly complicated?

Comment: @eryksun opening and closing the process, which seems to be more than running `os.startfile(...)`