# Get file location and names from Windows Camera

Tags: python, windows, winapi, camera

I was running into troubles using `QCamera` with focusing and other things, so I thought I can use the Camerasoftware served with `Windows 10`. Based on the thread of [opening the Windows Camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56523525/open-windows-camera-from-python-application) I did some trials to aquire the taken images and use them for my program. In the [documentation](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-Camera) and its API I didn't find usable snippets (for me), so I created the hack mentioned below. It assumes that the images are in the **target folder** `'C:\\Users\\*username*\\Pictures\\Camera Roll'` which is mentioned in the registry (See below), but I don't know if this is reliable or how to get the proper key name.
I don't think that this is the only and cleanest solution. So, my question is how to get taken images and open/close the Camera proper?
Actualy the function waits till the `'WindowsCamera.exe'` has left the processlist and return newly added images / videos in the **target folder**

In the registry I found:

Entry: `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders` with key name `{3B193882-D3AD-4eab-965A-69829D1FB59F}`for the **target folder**. I don't think that this key is usable.

### Working example of my hack:

```
import subprocess
import pathlib
import psutil

def check_for_files(path, pattern):
    print(" check_for_files:", (path, pattern))
    files = []
    for filename in pathlib.Path(path).rglob(pattern):
        files.append (filename)
    return files

def get_Windows_Picture(picpath):
    prefiles = check_for_files(picpath, '*.jpg')
    x = subprocess.call('start microsoft.windows.camera:',  shell=True)
    processlist = [proc.info['name'] for proc in psutil.process_iter (['name'])]
    while 'WindowsCamera.exe' in processlist:
        processlist = [proc.info['name'] for proc in psutil.process_iter (['name'])]
    postfiles = check_for_files(picpath, '*.jpg')
    newfiles = []
    for file in postfiles:
        if file not in prefiles:
            newfiles.append(str(file))
    return newfiles
if __name__ == "__main__":
    picpath = str (pathlib.Path ("C:/Users/*user*/Pictures/Camera Roll"))
    images = get_Windows_Picture(picpath)
    print("Images:", images)
```

Comment: This is a prime example of the [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info). Shouldn't you instead be fixing the code that's failing to properly take photographs as desired?

Comment: You're right, but after struggling for days sometimes it's easier to take  3 times the right corner instead 1 time the left one.

Comment: You could have asked about your failed attempt to do the right thing, though, and contributed to SO's mission: Providing a database of programming problems with quality solutions.

Comment: I agree with you but if you are in the forest you can't see all trees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Camera Roll` is a "[known Windows folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/known-folders)" which means some APIs can retrieve the exact path (even if it's non-default) for you:

- [`SHGetKnownFolderPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetknownfolderpath)
- [`SHGetKnownFolderIDList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetknownfolderidlist)
- [`SHSetKnownFolderPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shsetknownfolderpath)

The [`knownfolderid`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/knownfolderid) documentation will give you the constant name of the required folder (in your case `FOLDERID_CameraRoll`). As you can see in the linked page, the **default** is `%USERPROFILE%\Pictures\Camera Roll` (It's the default, so this doesn't mean it's the same for everyone).

The problem in Python is that you'll need to use [`ctypes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) which can be cumbersome  some times (especially in your case when you'll have to deal with GUIDs and releasing the memory returned by the API).

This [gist](https://gist.github.com/mkropat/7550097) gives a good example on how to call `SHGetKnownFolderPath` from Python with ctypes. In your case you'll only need the `CameraRoll` member in the `FOLDERID` class so you can greatly simplify the code.

Side note: Don't poll for the process end, just use the [`wait()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait) function on the Popen object.

Comment: That was what I was searching for. How did you find this?
According the `wait()` I had some troubles retrieving the filenames, I will work on this the next days.

Comment: I've tried the `wait()` but it seems that the command  `x = subprocess.Popen('start microsoft.windows.camera:',  shell=True)` is not waiting for the closed app.